# Getting all possible directions from a geo point in osm2po

Tags: routing, osm2po

Wanted to share some of my code I use to get all possible routes from a random geopoint in osm2po.

```
 Graph graph = loadGraph();

 OverlayNode node = new OverlayNode(lat, lon);
 if (node.snap(graph, (int[])null)) {
        List<Integer> edges = new LinkedList<>();
        edges.add(node.getEdgeIdx());
        int reverseId = graph.findReverseEdge(node.getEdgeIdx());

        if (reverseId > 0) {
            edges.add(reverseId);
        }
        for (int edgeIdx : edges) {
            routeFrom(edgeIdx);
        }
    }
```

Seems to work like I want to work (only getting the reverse edge if it's drivable) - but is this the correct way to do this or is there already a method that will give me all edges for a given point?

Comment: are you looking for outgoing edges of real crossings only or rather random, even virtual locations somewhere on arbitrary edges?

Comment: No, just real edges for real crossings. I basically just want to know all possible legal ways to drive out of the current point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the answer in the comment above:
It is sufficient to use the static Graph.

The OverlayGraph is not needed here:

```
Graph graph = new Graph(...)
int vertexId = graph.findClosestVertexId(lat, lon); // Find nearest crossing
int[] edgeIdxs = graph.findOutgoingEdges(vertexId);
```

`edgeIdxs` is an array of indexes (*pointers*) to the edges inside the graph

Further informations of the edge can be retrieved by getting one of the
getEdge*()-arrays. e.g.: Determine sourceId and targetId of a given edge:

```
int targetId = graph.getEdgeTargetIds()[edgeIdx];
int sourceId = graph.getEdgeSourceIds()[edgeIdx];
```

In order to retrieve geometry or (street)name call

`graph.lookupGeometry(edgeIdx)` or `graph.lookupName(edgeIdx)`

or for lazy people: lookup almost everything: `graph.lookupSegment(edgeIdx)`

Comment: So one way it doesn't work for me is for one-directional streets - so if let's say my street goes from 1 (source) to 2 (target), and I click in the middle, I'm really only interested in this particular edge 1->2 as my starting street. But if findClosestVertexId returns 2 for me, I don't really know where the street starts - I could get all incoming edges but then I wouldn't know if I'm on 3->2 or 1->2 street, for example.

Comment: Then it's a misunderstanding. I asked if it is sufficient to find crossings (see above). To find the closest edge, your first approach was already correct. `node.snap(...)` returns the needed information, namely exactly one edge (forward). To find the reverse edge (if exists) call `graph.findReverseEdge(...)` as you did. In some rare cases a vertex is closer than an edge. Therefore call `node.isOnVertex()` and/or `node.isOnEdge()` before and fallback to `graph.findOutgoingEdges(node.getId())` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Carsten. I just run into a situation where edgeId was < 0, and I couldn't figure out why. Now I know :)